# bulkTransfer "Transfer failed."

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-app

I'm not getting any kind of transfer to happen between my chrome app and a simple device just waiting for data to come in on its uart rx line.  The device's interface's endpoint's type is `bulk`, although I've tried every transfer type available (`control`, `bulk`, `isochronous`, and `interrupt`).  Examples from [here](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_usb).  I've also tried claiming the device, but that does not seem to be applicable if using `findDevices` and fails as well.

I'm assuming that by finding the device, I know that it has been discovered, permissions are OK and that it has been opened OK.

I'm using a [UART-to-USB adapter](http://www.ftdichip.com/Products/Cables/USBTTLSerial.htm) on a mac.  I've spoken to the same hardware setup using pysusb and a python script, so I know it can be done.

```
var DEVICE_INFO = {"vendorId": 1027, "productId": 24577};

var searchForUsbDevice = function() {
  chrome.usb.findDevices(DEVICE_INFO, onDeviceFound);
}

var onDeviceFound = function(devices) {    
  if (devices) {
    if (0 < devices.length) {
      if (1 === devices.length) {
        device_ = devices[0];
        console.log("Device found. And opened?");
        getInterfaces();
        getConfiguration();
        //claimDevice();
        investigateDevice();
      } else {
        console.log("Ensure one and ONLY ONE device is plugged in.");
      }
    } else {
      console.log("Device could not be found");
      setTimeout(searchForUsbDevice, 1000);
    }
  } else {
    console.log("Permission denied.");
  }
};

var investigateDevice = function() {
  testBulkTransfer();
  //testIsochronousTransfer();
  //testInterruptTransfer();
  //testControlTransfer();
  setTimeout(investigateDevice, 1000);
};

var testBulkTransfer = function() {
  var transferInfo = {
    "direction": "out",
    "endpoint": 1,
    "data": new Uint8Array([32, 2, 1, 2]).buffer
  };

  chrome.usb.bulkTransfer(device_, transferInfo, function(info) {
    if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
      console.log("info: " + JSON.stringify(info));
      console.log("runtime error: " + JSON.stringify(chrome.runtime.lastError.message));
      return;
    }

    console.log("transfer result: " + ((0 === info.resultCode) ? "succeeded" : "failed"));
  });
};

var getConfiguration = function() {
  chrome.usb.getConfiguration(device_, function(config) {
    if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
      console.log("runtime error: " + JSON.stringify(chrome.runtime.lastError.message));
      return;
    }
    console.log("config: ");
    console.log(config);
  });
};

var getInterfaces = function() {
  chrome.usb.listInterfaces(device_, function(descriptors) {
    if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
      console.log("runtime error: " + JSON.stringify(chrome.runtime.lastError.message));
      return;
    }
    console.log("descriptors: ");
    console.log(descriptors);
  });
};
```

Comment: Have you tried quitting Chrome? If you've been debugging code, it's hard to be sure which state the Chrome process is in. Quitting Chrome (and making sure you've really quit every Chrome process on your machine) resets the state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The appropriate API for that UART-to-USB adapter is [chrome.serial](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/serial), NOT `chrome.usb`.

https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_serial